# Error "AttributeError 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable' " using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I followed all steps to install Beautiful Soup, but it still comes out with this error:

> AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'

[image: Stacktrace]

I am using Python 3.10.

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Don't post images of code, error, etc. Copy/paste as text. Provide [mre] of your code as well as any relevant info like python version.

Comment: It looks like BeautifulSoup does not support python3.10 yet. (In 3.10 the deprecated aliases to Collections Abstract Base Classes from the collections module were [removed](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#removed)). . Downgrade your python version

Comment: i sort of understand the downvotes, but it's a good question. though not a pure programming question it's about programming environment so on-topic and the fix is not obvious. if there's no duplicate we need it. and i'd gladly upvote @buran's answer. i've proposed an edit

Comment: This *should* just work without issue on BeautifulSoup 4.6.1 or up (a release that was already 3 years old when this question was posted).

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69515086/edit) (it covers command-line input/output as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 56):

`collections.Callable` has been [moved to `collections.abc.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#removed) in python 3.10+. A hacky solution is to add the reference back to `collections` before importing the problem library.

```
import collections
collections.Callable = collections.abc.Callable

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # for example
```

Comment: This hacking just works for me. Invoke the problem library after running these codes yield correct result for me.

Comment: This function removed(https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#removed)

Comment: my code is a trick for use this function. (function moved to abc submodule )

Comment: Thank you! Debugged this issue for ~4 hours. :)

Answer (score 26):

This solution worked for me:

1. Navigate to `Python310\Lib\site-packages\pyreadline` in your file browser.
2. Open `py3k_compat.py` in an text editor.
3. Change the 8th line from which should be return `isinstance(x, collections.Callable)` to return `isinstance(x, collections.abc.Callable)`.
4. Save, exit and then retry.

Answer (score 12):

You can uninstall the Python package `pyreadline` and install `pyreadline3`, which is an updated fork !

Comment: This worked for me, today 2023-04-13, when getting this same error trying to use pdbpp. Just "pip uninstall pyreadline" then "pip install pyreadline3". Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me as well. This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 7):

I got the same AttributeError.

Then I looked inside the Python *lib* → *collections* folder. It has [ABCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)#Abstract_and_concrete) (abstract base classes) made separately in version 3.3 and above.

So resolve the error by opening */bs4/elements.py* in an editor and replace *collections.callable* with *collections.abc.callable*. Hence the callable attribute can be easily accessed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

Change "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-ackages\pyreadline\py3k_compat.py" - 8th code as below: `return isinstance(x, collections.abc.Callable)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Re *"8th code"*: Do you mean *"8th line"*? (*"8th code line"*)? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72569342/edit), not here in comments (******** ***without*** ******** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: There is dwindling hope: *"Last seen more than a month ago"*

Answer (score 2):

Beautiful Soup did not work with 3.10.

Reinstall with 3.9.

Comment: Maybe that was a more appropriate name :-)

Answer (score 1):

This error message indicates you have an old version of Beautiful Soup. The issue was already [fixed](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eleonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/revision/452) back in Beautiful Soup 4.6.1, a release that came out in 2018. As of this writing, Beautiful Soup is up to version 4.11.1.

Update your Beautiful Soup, and the problem should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error while trying to run [manticore](https://github.com/trailofbits/manticore), but apparently none of the answers were answering Mac users. So if you are on Mac and getting the same error, you have got to navigate to

> lib/python3.10/site-packages/wasm/types.py Line 246

and change

`isinstance(cur_field, collections.Callable)` to `isinstance(cur_field, collections.abc.Callable)`

Comment: Why is it different? Due to using a different installer (not a rhetorical question)? [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager))? Could it just be due to different Python versions (not a rhetorical question)?

Answer (score 0):

I had Beautiful Soup in a folder within the same folder as the Python program, as opposed to "installing" it.

So in that folder, I opened `element.py` and replaced all `collections.Callable` with `collections.abc.Callable`.

Python version 3.10.7

Comment: What platform? A PC with [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux)? What distribution and version? [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows)? What edition and version?

Comment: I don't recall, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

instead of installing the zip folder of bs4, install it using your command prompt by typing: -
pip install beautifulsoup4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).