# Python on Windows starts with `AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'`

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, terminal

Just installed python 3 on windows and started it on the terminal using the command "python". Then I had this error:

```console
C:\Users\User>python
Python 3.10.8 (tags/v3.10.8:aaaf517, Oct 11 2022, 16:50:30) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Failed calling sys.__interactivehook__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site.py", line 446, in register_readline
    import readline
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\readline.py", line 34, in <module>
    rl = Readline()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 422, in __init__
    BaseReadline.__init__(self)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 62, in __init__
    mode.init_editing_mode(None)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\emacs.py", line 633, in init_editing_mode
    self._bind_key('space',       self.self_insert)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\basemode.py", line 162, in _bind_key
    if not callable(func):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\py3k_compat.py", line 8, in callable
    return isinstance(x, collections.Callable)
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'
>>>
```

([original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFqlw.png))

I'm not understanding why I'm getting this error.

Comment: have you tried using it? it looks like it works. the >>> signifies its asking for input. try typing 3+5 and hit enter. do you get 8?

Comment: I think it will still work. But your `py3k_compat.py` is wrong. It should be `return instance(x, collections.abc.Callable)` I suppose you can manually change that if needed.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is caused by the outdated package `pyreadline` present as a package importable by the Python installation. As this provides the `readline` module for Windows version of Python, the default `site` module will be able to import it and trigger the error.  This outdated and no longer maintained package tries to import `collections.abc.Callable` from the deprecated location `collections.Callable`, [it will fail under Python 3.10](https://github.com/pyreadline/pyreadline/issues/73) as that deprecated import has been [fully removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53978542/how-to-use-collections-abc-from-both-python-3-8-and-python-2-7).

To solve this issue, just simply uninstall the `pyreadline` package, and should the features provided by readline is desirable, install the [`pyreadline3`](https://pypi.org/project/pyreadline3/) package instead, which is currently maintained (as of 2022) and will provide the features expected from that package.

Please do ensure that `pyreadline` is first uninstalled before installing `pyreadline3`:

```console
C:\Users\User>python -m pip uninstall pyreadline
Found existing installation: pyreadline 2.1
Uninstalling pyreadline-2.1:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pyreadline-2.1-py3.10.egg-info
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\*
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\readline.py
Proceed (Y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled pyreadline-2.1

C:\Users\User>python -m pip install pyreadline3
Collecting pyreadline3
  Downloading pyreadline3-3.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 95.2/95.2 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pyreadline3
Successfully installed pyreadline3-3.4.1

C:\Users\User>python
Python 3.10.8 (tags/v3.10.8:aaaf517, Oct 11 2022, 16:50:30) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Note that potential package conflicts may happen as both the `pyreadline` and `pyreadline3` packages provide the `readline` module if both these packages are installed at the same time within the same Python environment/installation.

Alternatively, do as suggested by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73353426/) which was posted under the question about BeautifulSoup, as there are other widely used Python packages that have not corrected this deprecated import in a timely manner.

Answer (score 0):

try

[BeautifulSoup AttributeError 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69515086/beautifulsoup-attributeerror-collections-has-no-attribute-callable)

```
Navigate to Python310\Lib\site-packages\pyreadline in your file browser.
Open py3k_compat.py in an text editor.
Change the 8th line from which should be return isinstance(x, collections.Callable) to return isinstance(x, collections.abc.Callable).
Save, exit and then retry.
```

or just reinstall python